# Can't return from clock view to calendar

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have add to my page Bootstrap datepicker. It works, but if I chose clock view in calendar view I can't back to calendar and disable that view.

Includes:

```
<script src="../resources/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../resources/js/moment.js"></script>
<script src="../resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../resources/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="/resources/js/dodajDP.js"></script>
<script src="../resources/js/zegarodliczajacy.js"></script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/fonts/awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
```

add picker:
HTML

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Rozpoczęcie zawodów:</label>
  <div id="datetimepicker1" class="input-group col-sm-4 input-group">
    <input class='form-control form-date' type="text" name="startZawodow" value="<?php echo $_POST[" startZawodow "];?>" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class='col-sm-4'>
    <span>
      <?php sprawdzPoprawnoscCzasuFormularza("timestamp", "startZawodow"); sprawdzCzyNiePuste("koniecZawodow");?>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function dodajZData(id) {
  $(id).datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
    locale: 'PL'
  });
}
```

What is wrong?
Screen:
[image]

Comment: So what happens when you click on the calendar icon? It must show some kind of error in console.

Comment: nothing, console have no output. It's like thist action disable all js on website

Comment: Bootstrap datetimepicker requires moment.js. I don't see a reference to that in your code snip.

Comment: the second one ;-)
<script src="../resources/js/moment.js"></script>